# Cannot start npm after installing react ERR! react-scripts start

Tags: redux, react-redux, node-modules, npm-start

While using redux with react. I was trying to do npm start for my app(reactwithredux) after installing react-redux and redux libraries . I see this error below. I'm trying to figure it out myself, but no luck so far. Please help me out.

> 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   errno 1 npm ERR! reactwithredux@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` npm
>   ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   reactwithredux@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\preet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-09-21T01_19_43_724Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Try following

- npm run cache clean --force
- rm -rf node_modules (in project
  directory)
- npm install

If this doesn't solve the error, please provide a link to repo need to take a look at package.json.